# Executing the same SSIS Task via different Route

Tags: ssis, constraints, expression, pipeline

I want to execute the same task in two different conditions.  They are
1. If the job is successful and RowCount is 0.
2. If the job is successful and it has executed other tasks.

I tried to use the same SQL Execute Task but regardless of the outcome, it does not execute that task.  Please see the screenshot below.
[image]

But I replicated that job and connected directly to the other job.  At that time, it works.  Does it mean that we can't have different route to execute the same task?
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double click the green arrow. You will have the following dialog:

[image]

Choose the "Logical OR" like in the above image. This will make your green lines become dotted. Now you can connect several arrows to the same task.

The way you had the task worked like an `AND`, meaning that the task would only execute if BOTH the constraints were successful.

Comment: Oh, yes.  I thought it applied to the Evaluation options because I chose the Evaluation operation: Constraint and Expression.  So, I thought I must choose Logical AND.  Thanks very much.